# R, subset data.table turning off wildcard search

Tags: r, data.table, subset, wildcard

I've been given a datafile where one of the fields (columns) is called code_id.  Some of the codes in this field include "22K..", "22K4.", and "22K7.".  Now I'm trying to subset a data.table to pull out the rows containing explicit values 22K.., and no others.  My first attempt, treats the "." as a wildcard for any character and thus I get all three.  I've tried several permutations of "escaping" the . using single or double \ characters, both with and outwith quotation marks but nothing seems to work. I guess I'm trying to stop
R treating . as a wildcard and get it to treat it as a literal ".".  What basic syntax am am I missing.  The code attempted is :

```
K22Kcodes <- ClinicalTable[code_id == "22K.."]
```

Thx. J

Comment: There are no wildcards with `==`... please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: If you want to use regex, use the `%like%` or `%ilike%` operator instead of `==` with data.table. Or simply `grep()`.

Comment: Thx. I produced a MWE and it worked correctly, went back to my original and it also worked correctly! Not sure what I've done or how I've fixed it!